# Doubt about a formula

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

In the slides of my professors there is written that

$$ P(A|B,X) = \dfrac{P(B|A,X) P(A,X)}{P(B,X)} $$

Is it correct? And how it is so? The Bayes theorem states that

$$ P(A|B) = P(B|A) \dfrac{P(A)}{P(B)} $$

So by the Bayes theorem I think that it should be that:

$$ P(A|B,X) = P(B,X|A) \dfrac{P(A)}{P(B,X)} $$

Comment: Because "$,X$" appears everywhere in the first formula, it is superfluous, so drop it: what remains?

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I didn't know about that rule that if it appears everywhere we can drop it. Why we can do that?

Comment: Because it's superfluous: explicitly writing "$X$" as a condition of every probability (in this general context) tells us exactly nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation}
P(A, B, X) = P(A|B,X)P(B,X)
\end{equation}
This is obvious, if you think of $A \& X$ as a single event, say $C$.
Similarly
\begin{equation}
P(A, B, X) = P(B|A,X)P(A,X)
\end{equation}
And your relation immediately follows.